# Intersecting a dynamic number of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two relations, `a` and `b`, with attributes given by

```
CREATE TABLE a (id int, b_id int)
CREATE TABLE b (id int)
```

for which I can assume that all pairs of values in `a` and all values in `b` are unique, and which will be based in an SQL Server 2016 database.

A given element of `b` defines a subset of `a.id` given by those elements for which the corresponding `a.b_id` is the given value, and my goal is to produce the intersection of all those subsets.

Say, for instance, that `a` contains the six values,

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3)
```

Then the expected results would include the following:

```
b: (1), (2), (3). Expected result: (1)
b: (1), (2).      Expected result: (1)
b: (2).           Expected result: (1), (2), (3)
b: (2), (3).      Expected result: (1), (3)
b: [Empty].       Expected result: (1), (2), (3)
```

Using uniqueness, for the case of non-empty `b`, this can be achieved through

```
SELECT a.id FROM a
JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(a.id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b)
```

but this feels clunky, given that SQL has an `INTERSECT` operator readily available, and were I to write the same query in, say, LINQ, I would simply aggregate intersections. It also fails to produce the desired result in the case of empty `b` without treating that as a special case.

So, the question becomes: Is there a more idiomatic way of performing the above query, which also works properly for trivial `b`?

Comment: **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b91f25fdbc0bd5851545ff3725d323f)**

Comment: @lad2025: That's certainly a concise way to take care of that case! Note that it does produce incorrect results if `b` is {2, 3}, but replacing the `LEFT JOIN` by an `INNER JOIN` takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a relational division [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)), [2](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/soule/teaching/2016-fall/db/division.pdf)].

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT, b_id INT);
CREATE TABLE b (id INT);

INSERT INTO a VALUES
  (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),
  (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3);

DECLARE @i INT = 0;
WHILE @i < 5 BEGIN
  TRUNCATE TABLE b;
  IF @i = 0 INSERT b VALUES (1), (2), (3);
  IF @i = 1 INSERT b VALUES (1), (2);
  IF @i = 2 INSERT b VALUES (2);
  IF @i = 3 INSERT b VALUES (2), (3);
  SELECT DISTINCT x.id
  FROM a AS x
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM b AS y
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM a AS z
      WHERE z.id = x.id AND z.b_id=y.id
    )
  )
  SET @i = @i + 1;
END;
```

[Test it online](http://rextester.com/MDCCZ44682).

Comment: Excellent; even if it does so in the negative, this readily answers the question on idiomaticity. In particular, the references suggest that the query provided in @lad2025's answer is likely as succinct as it will get.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your approach to handle empty set case by using:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a
LEFT JOIN  b on a.b_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(b.id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fee259ed2d31ec46248f8c6cdfbd5e66)**   | **[DBFiddle Demo - all test cases](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=87e6bb45054c01442fe3ea01fa1cc07b)**

Extra: [Transient Data](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/unit-tests-on-transient-data) (used in second demo)

---

**EDIT:**

Another approach to handle empty set and leave `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id FROM a
JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(a.id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b)
UNION
SELECT a.id
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo 3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ed4541f89b6ff2b437ed77afef1c77c)**

Comment: Yep, that does indeed take care of the trivial case. I'll leave the question open a bit longer in case anyone wants to touch on the part of the question concerning obtaining the same results using fundamental set operations. Is there any reason you prefer `LEFT JOIN` over `INNER JOIN`? One of the things that bugged me about the original solution is that once you `INNER JOIN`, it no longer matters if you count on `a.id` or `b.id` which smells a bit.

Comment: @fuglede I exchanged `INNER JOIN` -> `LEFT JOIN` plus changed the column in `HAVING COUNT(a.id)` to `HAVING COUNT(b.id)`. Aggregation functions skips `NULL` so now it is handling all your cases. If I stick with `INNER JOIN` then `a` JOIN `empty` will always be empty and you won't get result at all. Of course I could mitigate it with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Ah, right. In fact, then `OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b)` ends up always being true, and you can remove that entirely; that is, `SELECT a.id FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id GROUP BY a.id HAVING COUNT(b.id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b)` does the job.